# RAML include and multiple inheritance

Tags: raml

We have been writing our RAML specification and we've been defining our data types in separate files. Something like:

```
%#RAML 1.0 DataType
type: !include ../base-type.raml
description: Lorem ipsum
properties:
    foo: string
```

Which works fine, but according to the RAML specification you can use multiple inheritance by using an YAML array type for the `type` field.

But however, if I try to do this with includes, I always get the same error: `INHERITING_UNKNOWN_TYPE`

I've tried it like this:

```
type: [!include ../base-type.raml]

type: [!include ../base-type.raml, !include ../another-type.raml]

type:
  - !include ../base-type.raml
  - !include ../another-type.raml
```

But all yield the same error. Am I doing this wrong or is this not supported in RAML?

Answer (score 3):

Multiple inheritance can be defined as you say, but I don't think it works with inlined types.

So you should first specify the definition of the types and then specify the multiple inheritance using just the keys of the previously defined types.

For example:

```
types:
  Person:
    type: object
    properties:
      name: string
  Employee:
    type: object
    properties:
      employeeNr: integer
```

Once you do that you can, create a new type which inherits from those, e.g.:

```
Teacher:
    type: [ Person, Employee ]
```

and then use that type in some resource:

```
/someresource:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: Teacher
```

or directly specify the types as array there:

```
/someresource:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: [ Person, Employee ]
```

These also works with includes, e.g.:

```
types: !include myTypes.raml
```

but I didn't use the includes in the examples above to be clearer.

More info [here](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#multiple-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've found out how to include multiple files with types (though it wasn't represented in documentation examples) - in the root of RAML-file just add:

```
uses:
  file: path/to/file.raml
  otherfile: path/to/otherFile.raml
  yetanother: path/to/yetanother.raml
```

Comment: According to the spec the `uses` key imports libraries. That means, to refer to something imported by this solution you would need to use `file.MyType` instead of `MyType` directly. At least that's what's documented.